# What is a good way to aggregate dataframes in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to aggregate dataframes in AWS Glue. I have used the following pySpark code to perform the aggregation:

```
mydataframe.groupby('id').agg({'value', 'operation'})
```

Is there a better way to perform the aggregation in AWS Glue?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with better way? More efficient? More readable?

Answer (score 0):

I convert it to `Dataframe` using `pyspark` and do the aggregation, then converting it back to `Dynamicframe`. However, it seems that you need to manually add partitions to the dataframes.

Comment: rileyss@, could you share a code snippet for referance?